# Change field conditional statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I've  got a table which looks like:

```
>Date--Country--Courier--Division--Volume
>
>datetime--varchar--varchar--varchar--varchar--int
>
>datetime--varchar--varchar--varchar--varchar--int
```

All this data is gathered in a temp table and represents a month worth data.

The final scope is to change the countries which have TOTAL volume less than a value to 'others'.

FOR example:

```
>Country -- Volume
>
>Germany -- 1200
>
>Albania -- 250
```

I want to change it to:

```
>Country -- Volume
> 
>Germany -- 1200
>
>Other -- 250
```

I've been trying to make an IF statement based on

```
SUM(Volume) OVER(PARTITION BY Country) < x
```

But it looks like I m far from achieving this.

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Your `SUM` is the right approach (but you can probably get away with a `GROUP BY`, not an `OVER`). Stick it in a common table expression, then query that with a `Country = CASE WHEN Volume < x THEN 'Other' ELSE Country END`, then query *that* with `SUM(Volume) ... GROUP BY Country`.

Comment: DDL => data definition language. In this case, the create table statment. DML => data manipulation language. In this case, the insert into statement. Also, your desired output is not clear. Do you want to update the values in the table or just select them?

Comment: Update them. No change to data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a logic point of view, you could proceed in the following way:

```
DECLARE @threshold int = 250;
SELECT
   0 AS Priority, 
   Country, 
   Volume
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE Volume >= @threshold
UNION ALL
SELECT 
   1 AS Priority, 
   'Others' AS Country,
   SUM(Volume) AS Volume
FROM YourTable
WHERE Volume < @threshold
ORDER BY Priority, Volume DESC
```

Given that yor data could be:

```
Country - Volume
----------------
Germany - 1000
Italy   - 500
France  - 300
Albania - 120
Spain   - 100
Sweden  - 90
```

You'd get:

```
Country - Volume
----------------
Germany - 1000
Italy   - 500
France  - 300
Others  - 310 -- equals to sum of countries under @threshold value
```